# i am getting local variable referenced before assignment when i use that variable in try-except block

Tags: python, variables, try-except

i am getting

```
local variable 'flag' referenced before assignment
```

in python. what am i doing wrong here?

```
flag = 0
def abc():
    while flag <= 10:
        try:
            print(10/0)
        except Exception:
            print('yo')
            flag += 1

abc()
```

Comment: The fact that the function contains an assignment to the variable makes it a local variable by default.  You would need to add `global flag` to the top of the function to make it refer to the same `flag` that you set outside of the function.

Comment: Precisely, or why don't you assign flag in the function body at the top?

Comment: Playing with global scope in functions is generally bad practice though

Comment: @stephanmg, i am going to use flag vaiable in multiple functions. thats why i declared it globally.

Answer (score 1):

```
flag = 0
def abc(argument):
    while argument <= 10:
        try:
            print(10/0)
        except Exception:
            print('yo')
            argument += 1

abc(flag)
```

Comment: `print(flag) # still 0` probably not what they intended

Comment: if you add `return argument` and change the call to `flag = abc(flag)`, then it might be something.

Comment: your solution mentions _how this can be solved_ , question is _why is this happening in first place_ ... try to understand question first! virtual -1 for your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def abc():
    flag = 0
    while flag <= 10:
        try:
            print(10/0)
        except Exception:
            print('yo')
            flag += 1
    return flag

abc()
```

I'd use this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of referencing that variable in a try/catch, it's a matter of defining that variable outside the function you used it in. `flag` is declared outside of `abc()` and is not declared as global; therefore, python doesn't believe there's a variable named `flag` inside the function that it can use. (If I'm correct, `flag` is declared as being part of `__main__`, since you can print it below the call to `abc()` without issue.)

If you intended to use `flag` as nothing more than a counter, moving it inside the `def` works:

```py
def abc():
    flag = 0
    while flag <= 10:
        try:
            print(10/0)
        except Exception:
            print('yo')
            flag += 1

abc()
```

If, however, you intended to use it elsewhere, you would have to either declare it as global (**not** recommended) or declare it as a local variable and then return it. If it's defined externally, consider passing it in as a parameter to `abc`.

Answer (score -1):

You are a victim of variable scoping in Python. What you need is the `global` keyword ([great tutorial on the subject](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/)). In this case:

```
flag = 0

def abc():
    global flag
    while flag <= 10:
        try:
            print(10/0)
        except Exception:
            print('yo')
            flag += 1

abc()
```

Note the new `global flag` line at the beginning of `abc`'s definition. This tells the function that the keyword `flag` should come from the global scope, not the local scope.

As a side note, it is generally considered bad practice to use global variables, so I would recommend you think about your overall design. There are definitely valid times to use `global`, however, try to avoid it when possible.

Comment: I would not say something teaching beginners to use global variables can be called "great".

Comment: Updated to reflect the bad practice, however, it is still the valid answer case. I agree it should likely be passed in, or more likely the architecture changed, however it is the answer as to why that is happening and the way to fix that specific error.